# Regression with percentage dependent, log and linear independent

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, interpretation

I have read a lot of questions and answers but I am still confused for my case.
My dependent variable (employment growth) is measured : 
$$ \frac{((number\ of\ employees \ in \ year\ t) - (number \ of \ employees \ in  \ year \ t-1))}{[((number \ of \ employees \ in \ year \ t) + (number \ of  \ employees \ in \ year \ t-1))/2]}*100 $$
It is defined in percentage (%).
It can takes values from -100 to 100 (continuous).
1)I have an independent in log value.
2) I have an independent - indicator which can take values from 0 to 50 (continuous).
Let's say I have this:
$$ eg = 80 + 1.48 \ log(x) + 6.044 \ Indicator + \epsilon $$
How I interpret coefficient for each independent...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about it confuses you? Have you taken a course in regression?

Comment: So, my point is : 
1) For a 1% increase in x , we expect a 1.48 % increase in eg.
2) For a 1-unit increase in indicator, we expect a 6.044 increase in eg. 
Am I right ?
The thing is that eg is already defined in percentage (%) , so I think there is something wrong with my thoughts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interpret it like a regular regression (as you did in your reply to my comment, above).  However, since the dependent variable is bounded by -100 and 100, regular OLS regression might not be appropriate and the regression equation might make nonsensical predictions. [This thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11985/how-to-model-bounded-target-variable) or [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111108/model-for-continuous-dependent-variable-bounded-between-0-and-1) may be helpful.